# Kubernetes storage in different AZs

Tags: kubernetes

**Question 1:**

If I have 2 webapp pods. Assume, Both are scheduled in different nodes (same AZ). There is a pvc defined in pod.yml file. If I create a file in mounted Path in one pod, Is another pod (on different node) able to see it?

**Question 2:**

Same scenario but assume both Nodes are in Different AZs. Will there be 2 PVs in each AZ? If I create a file in mounted Path in one pod, Is another pod (on different node) able to see it?

Comment: Hello, I do think that your question lacks details. Especially on the part of storage configuration. Could you please include more details about the setup? Could you specify which exact storage option your`Pod` is using? (`YAML` definition of your `Pod` and storage would be helpful). Here you can find more on storage: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/

Comment: Depends on the storageclass and pv. Without more details assuming the defaults and AWS (since you mentioned AZ's)  The answer is no for both Q1 and Q2. EBS is not replicated across AZ's. The default storage class in AWS uses EBS and it gets attached to a single worker which cannot be mounted from a pod on another worker.